# How to convert '2012-02-06T23:18:17Z' to DateTime

Tags: c#, xml, datetime, itunes

I'm creating an application to parse the xml provided by iTunes in C# and i'm having some issues with the fields 'Date Added' and 'Date Modified' which have this syntax:

2012-02-06T23:18:17Z

i've tried this:

```
DateModified = DateTime.ParseExact(s.Element("DateModified").ToString(), "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

but the application fails with an FormatException

```
{"String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe `s.Element("DateModified").ToString()` is not outputting what you think it is.

This works as expected:

```
var d = DateTime.ParseExact("2012-02-06T23:18:17Z", "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
Console.WriteLine(d.ToString());
```

Comment: Just deleted my answer because, even though you don't need to use `ParseExact` for that string, I hadn't noticed that the input string *does* actually parse with that format string.  Well spotted!

Comment: This worked flawlessly... i didn't notice that s.Element("DateModified").ToString() was outputting:

     <DateModified>2012-02-06T23:18:17Z</DateModified>

Answer (score 6):

If you are using LINQ to XML, then you can just cast the element to `DateTime`; this automatically parses the date and time with the correct format string:

```
dateModified = (DateTime)s.Element("DateModified");
```

Otherwise, you can use `XmlConvert.ToDateTime`:

```
dateModified = XmlConvert.ToDateTime(s.Element("DateModified").Value, XmlDateTimeSerializationMode.Utc);
```

Answer (score 1):

Nothing fancy:

```
var str = "2012-02-06T23:18:17Z";
DateTime t = DateTime.Parse(str, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
t.ToUniversalTime();
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this is Linq to Xml you need to grab the *value* of the Element, so do this instead:

```
DateModified = DateTime.ParseExact(s.Element("DateModified").Value, "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```